# Cannot delete partition table from big query sometimes

Tags: google-bigquery

Currently I am using bq command to delete partition table in the bigquery
I did 3 commands today, and it seems like only 2 of them are workings.

```
bq rm -f -t 'dataset.tablex$20171017'
bq rm -f -t 'dataset.tablex$20171018'    
bq rm -f -t 'dataset.tablex$20171019'
I verified them using the following:
SELECT count(*) FROM [a:dataset.tablex] WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2017-10-17")
SELECT count(*) FROM [a:dataset.tablex] WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2017-10-18")
SELECT count(*) FROM [a:dataset.tablex] WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2017-10-19")
```

however, the last query, still gave me a count that is more than 0 while the other changed from a number to 0 after the bq command executed.

Is this a bug on the bq command, or i am doing it not correctly?
Please help

Comment: do you have streaming set to this table?

Comment: I am using dataflow library to write to bigquery. I guess it’s implemented as streaming inserts, but not sure

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I knew that streaming does not allow you to delete some rows by using the DELETE statement but does it block the table deletion too ?

Comment: @user2913464 does your account has the rights to delete table, you can check in the Google Console into the IAM section.

Comment: @Catheart, I believe so, I have successfully deleted some partitions before and I am the owner of the project.

Comment: For the Delete, seems like bq doesn't recognize it by showing "Unknown Token Delete", any suggestion on where to run the delete?